# Calm down initial tick of a force layout

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I've just started dabbling with d3, and find the learning curve quite steep. The process is completely different than what I am used to, and the mathematics are mostly way over my head.

Anyway, my project consists of a force layout representing map of integrations between systems. This part works out awesomely well, but I do have one major concern, which is also represented in the force directed layout demo on Michael Bostocks site:
When nodes are initiated, they seem to be rendered off canvas. After this, some serious physics math is taking over, simulating a gravitational pull which sends the nodes on a rather confusing path back and forth until they calm down and settle on some random coordinates. Although these movements are ripping cool the first time the demo is run, when you are trying to view the status of network interfaces from a company it admins point of view and the servers just wont stay still, it gets tiresome after a while.

I am sure I have the correct layout setup for this project, because I do want the servers to autolayout, I do want to visualize links between them. I am however ambivalent in regards to the gravitation effect.

I wonder; is it possible to set the initial position of each node manually, so that I can put them closer to the gravitational center and shorten the "bounce time" a bit?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

All the answers above misunderstood Øystein Amundsen's question.

The only way to stabilize the force upon it starts is to set node.x and node.y a proper value.
Please note that the node is the data of d3.js, not the represented DOM type.

For example, if you load

```
nodes = [{"id": a}, {"id": b}, {"id": c}]
```

into

```
d3.layout.force().nodes(nodes)
```

you have to set all .x and .y of all elements in array of nodes
it will be like this ( in coffeescript )

```
nodes = [{"id": a}, {"id": b}, {"id": c}]
for i in [0..2]
  nodes[i].x = 500 #the initial x position of node
  nodes[i].y = 300 #the initial y position of node
d3.layout.force().nodes(nodes).links(links)
```

then the nodes will start at the position when force.start().
this would avoid the chaos.

Comment: I think you are right. I aplaud your courage to go against the crowd. +1vote.

Comment: This works as intended. I will mark this as the correct answer, as it actually solved the problem instead of working around it. Thank you! :-)

Comment: If you already know the initial positions of all the nodes, then why would you need to use a force directed graph at all?

Comment: I do want d3 to autolayout my nodes for me. I just do not want it to be so chaotic. By forcing all nodes to have an initial position, they will all be laid out ON the canvas instead of outside it, which in turn makes them bounce less to not-at-all. The whole point of this project is to visualize network integrations between different systems. Not to showcase cool animations using physics simulation.

Comment: I think it is worth to mention that with setting the initial position of a lot of nodes to the same fixed position the repulsing forces will be extremely strong, making the layout be chaotic as well. One can prevent this by adding random "noise" to the initial positions. This solution was proposed by Lars Kotthoff in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127949/how-to-centre-new-nodes-in-a-forced-layout-in-d3?lq=1

Comment: Additionally you can set the inital node positions (described at https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7881887) and use D3's circle packing https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7882658 to give reasonable starting positions to avoid distracting jitter.

Answer (score 31):

Internally, under "normal" usage, the force layout repeatedly calls its own `tick()` method asynchronously (via a `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame`), until the layout settles on a solution. At that point its `alpha()` value equals or approaches 0.

So, if you want to "fast forward" through this solution process, you can synchronously call that `tick()` method over and over until the layout's alpha reaches a value that, for your specific requirements, constitutes a "close enough" solution. Like so:

```
var force = d3.layout.force(),
    safety = 0;
while(force.alpha() > 0.05) { // You'll want to try out different, "small" values for this
    force.tick();
    if(safety++ > 500) {
      break;// Avoids infinite looping in case this solution was a bad idea
    }
}

if(safety < 500) {
  console.log('success??');
}
```

After this code runs, you can draw your layout based on the state of the nodes. Or, if you're drawing your layout by binding to the tick event (ie `force.on('tick', drawMyLayout)`), you'll want to do the binding **after** this code runs, because otherwise you'll needlessly render the layout hundreds of times synchronously during the `while` loop.

JohnS has boiled down this approach to a single concise function. See his answer somewhere on this page.

Comment: The call to tick actually worked, but not quite satisfactory. The panel is just blank for a while, before the graph finally just appears - standing completely still. It would seem that this technique does not "disable" the animation, but prevents it from being visible. By tweaking the max "safety" value a bit, the app displays the graph at an earlier stage which results in less "bounciness" and not so long a wait until the graph is visible.
The alpha setting seemed to be ignored completely.
If nobody else comes up with a more "correct" answer, I will accept this. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Thanks for accepting this answer. I didn't realize you still wanted to see movement in the graph – rather than just having it come up in its final state. Yes: lowering "safety" would do that. Basically, repeatedly calling tick() in a synchronous loop is the same as letting it run asynchronously (at, say 30 frames per second) but all in an instant – until it settles, or slows down enough. The more I look at the d3 source it seems that this is the only way to "solve" the layout. A comment in the source code calls it [Simulated Annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing).

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. The movement is not so important, but the time before the graph appears, is. I do not want the app to be perceived as "slow" or "unresponsive". :-)

Comment: I'd like to find a way to set initial positions as well.  Sometimes it just looks strange to see all the nodes flying in from _the outer limits_ !  In my case, I'd like to set the initial node position based on the parent position.  Still looking...

Comment: @Inactivist If you are still looking for good way to initialize your nodes, I just set the x and y for each node to a random number. https://github.com/boccobrock/mythologyTree/blob/master/index.html#L83

Comment: @Boccobrock -- Thanks.  I've tried that, but there's still a lot of initial movement (things whizzing about) until the graph settles down.  The 'best' approach I've come up with so far involves placing child nodes 'near' the parent node, with a random offset based on the graph's link distance.  Here's my prototype app (requires Twitter OAuth login) if you're curious: http://whatevah.herokuapp.com/ (log in, enter a query term, drill down on users in left panel)

Answer (score 11):

I dealt with something a little like this a while ago. There are a few things to consider.

1) The iterating ticks are simulating a system that comes to equilibrium. So there is no way to avoid calling tick as many times as needed before the system settles and you have your auto-layout. That said, you do not need to update you visualization every tick for the simulation to work! The iterations will go a lot faster, in fact, if you don't. The relevant part of my code goes:

```
var iters = 600; // You can get decent results from 300 if you are pressed for time
var thresh = 0.001;
if(!hasCachedLayout || optionsChanged || minorOptionsChanged) {
    force.start(); // Defaults to alpha = 0.1
    if(hasCachedLayout) {
        force.alpha(optionsChanged ? 0.1 : 0.01);
    }
    for (var i = iters; i > 0; --i) {
        force.tick();
        if(force.alpha() < thresh) {
            //console.log("Reached " + force.alpha() + " for " + data.nodes.length + " node chart after " + (iters - i) + " ticks.");
            break;
        }
    }
    force.stop();
}
```

This runs synchronously and after it has run I create the dom elements for all the nodes and links. For small graphs this runs quite fast, but you will find there is a delay for larger graphs (100+ nodes) - they are simply much more computationally expensive.

2) You can cache / seed layouts. The force layout will uniformly distribute the nodes upon initialization *if no position is set!* So if you make sure your nodes have set x and y attribute these will be used. In particular when I am updating an existing graph I will re-use the x and y positions from a previous layout.

You will find with a good initial layout you will need a *lot* fewer iterations to reach a stable configuration. (This is what hasCachedLayout tracks in the code above). NB: If you are re-using the same nodes form the same layout then you will also have to make sure to set px and py to NaN or you will get weird results.

Comment: Thank you. You're explanation on how d3's internals work, is well put. I do have some questions though. On point 1; Why do you check first of hasCachedLayout is false to go on, and then inside that if block, you check again if hasCachedLayout has suddenly changed?

Comment: Point 2 is very logical and works like a charm. I've implemented a loop check each time I update my graph data, to see if nodes can be reused (have the same id). I then pursue to copy the original nodes x and y coordinates into my new data, and the graph experiences a slight jump before it settles. Works perfectly.

Comment: The second check inside is for the case where I had a cached layout but an option changed (for example gravity, link strength, node repulsion). The options will change the layout, but because I am starting with a stable layout I begin the loop much closer to the end - setting alpha to 0.01 instead of the default (0.1) means I expect many fewer iterations until stability.

Answer (score 8):

Based on other answers I have made this method:

```
function forwardAlpha(layout, alpha, max) {
  alpha = alpha || 0;
  max = max || 1000;
  var i = 0;
  while(layout.alpha() > alpha && i++ < max) layout.tick();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe `force.friction(0.5)`, or some other number lower than the default 0.9, would help? At least it gives a less chaotic impression upon page load.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var width = 960,
   height = 500;

 var fill = d3.scale.category20();

 var force = d3.layout.force()
   .size([width, height])
   .nodes([{}]) // initialize with a single node
   .linkDistance(30)
   .charge(-60)
   .on("tick", tick);

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height)
   .on("mousedown", mousedown);

 svg.append("rect")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);

 var nodes = force.nodes(),
   links = force.links(),
   node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
   link = svg.selectAll(".link");

  // var cursor = svg.append("circle")
  //     .attr("r", 30)
  //     .attr("transform", "translate(-100,-100)")
  //     .attr("class", "cursor");

 restart();

 function mousedown() {
   var point = d3.mouse(this),
     node = {
       x: width / 2,
       y: height / 2,
       "number": Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
     },
     n = nodes.push(node);

   // add links to any nearby nodes
   /*  nodes.forEach(function(target) {
      var x = target.x - node.x,
          y = target.y - node.y;
      if (Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) < 30) {
        links.push({source: node, target: target});
      }
    });
  */
   restart();
 }

 function tick() {
   link.attr("x1", function(d) {
       return d.source.x;
     })
     .attr("y1", function(d) {
       return d.source.y;
     })
     .attr("x2", function(d) {
       return d.target.x;
     })
     .attr("y2", function(d) {
       return d.target.y;
     });

   node.attr("transform", function(d) {
     return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
   });
 }

 function restart() {
   link = link.data(links);

   link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
     .attr("class", "link");

   node = node.data(nodes);

   // node.enter().insert("circle", ".cursor")
   //     .attr("class", "node")
   //     .attr("r", 5)
   //     .call(force.drag);

   var nodeEnter = node.enter().insert("svg:g", ".cursor")
     .attr("class", "node")
     .call(force.drag);

   nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
     .attr("r", 5)

   nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
     .attr("class", "textClass")
     .attr("x", 14)
     .attr("y", ".31em")
     .text(function(d) {
       return d.number;
     });

   force.start();
 }
```

```css
 rect {
   fill: none;
   pointer-events: all;
 }
 .node {
   fill: #000;
 }
 .cursor {
   fill: none;
   stroke: brown;
   pointer-events: none;
 }
 .link {
   stroke: #999;
 }
 .textClass {
   stroke: #323232;
   font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Droid Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-weight: normal;
   stroke-width: .5;
   font-size: 14px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

An example of what you might be looking for. It sets the x & y attributes of new nodes before inserting them into the layout. The desired location is the centre of the svg element.