# Log the x,y coordinates of nodes in a converged D3 force layout

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have a graph with about 600 nodes.  After a while, d3.layout.force() converges.  How can I display the (x,y) coordinates of the nodes such that I can store them as data and use them as a cached layout as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13495632/86924)?  The answer may be quite simple, as I'm a novice with javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the force layout converged, you can iterate over the list of nodes to get the current coordinates:

```
var force = d3.layout.force().nodes(nodes);

// after convergence
var positions = nodes.map(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });
```

This assumes that your browser supports `map`, if not see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

You can of course run this at every tick and save the result each time; this saves you figuring out when the layout has converged.