# Can't call force.tick() from a force graph with a tree layout

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I have a visualisation based on the [force-collapsable example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html) and I'd like to speed up or skip the initial node movements to bring the graph to equilibrium as soon as possible.

I've followed the advice in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13464833/599068) and called tick() from my code but it doesn't work in the force-collabsable example because there is no tick or alpha method on the force object.

Heres what my code looks like after the modifications, I've removed the on tick call and added the force.tick() call at the end:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()  // line 38 in the example
    //.on("tick", tick)        // commented out as I call tick instead
    .charge(function(d) { return d._children ? -d.size / 100 : -30; })
    .linkDistance(function(d) { return d.target._children ? 80 : 30; })
    .size([w, h - 160]);

function update() {            // line 56 in the example
  var nodes = flatten(root),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

  force                        // line 60 in the example
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .start();

  force.tick()                 // added by me to cause a tick and the point of error
```

but the call fails with 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' because the method isn't there.

The force object has the following values when I call it (taken from the Chrome debugger):

`charge: function (x) {
distance: function (x) {
drag: function () {
friction: function (x) {
gravity: function (x) {
linkDistance: function (x) {
linkStrength: function (x) {
links: function (x) {
nodes: function (x) {
on: function (type, listener) {
resume: function () {
size: function (x) {
start: function () {
stop: function () {
theta: function (x) {
proto: Object`

Why is the force object in this example different to other force layout examples that don't use the tree layout? How can I call tick() directly?

Comment: There's no link to an answer.

Comment: can you post the relevant code? also the line number of the JS error would be helpful, so we know what's undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I removed the referecnes to d3.geom.js and d3.layout.js I could call tick() and not have a negative effect on my layout without these files.